# How to assign static fields in bytecode using byte-buddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm trying to write a ByteBuddy Plugin to generate some class files which will be included in a jar. One class file needs to have some static constants defined, such as:

```java
public static final Value foo = new Value("bar");
```

Where `Value` is some arbitrary class.

Here is my plugin code:

```java
public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin.WithInitialization {
    public static class Value {
        private final String foo;

        public Value(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }
    }
    public Map<TypeDescription, byte[]> initialize(ClassFileLocator classFileLocator) {
        try {
            DynamicType.Builder<Object> type = new ByteBuddy()
                    .subclass(Object.class)
                    .name("com.example.ExampleGenerated")
                    .defineField("foo", TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(Value.class),
                            Visibility.PUBLIC, Ownership.STATIC, FieldManifestation.FINAL)
                    .invokable(MethodDescription::isTypeInitializer)
                    .intercept(FixedValue.reference(new Value("foo")));

            try (DynamicType.Unloaded<Object> unloaded = type.make()) {
                return unloaded.getAllTypes();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public DynamicType.Builder<?> apply(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassFileLocator classFileLocator) {
        return builder;
    }
    public void close() {}
    public boolean matches(TypeDescription target) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which produces the following class file (decompiled):

```java
public class ExampleGenerated {
    public static final ExamplePlugin.Value foo;

    public ExampleGenerated() {
    }

    static {
        ExamplePlugin.Value var10000 = value$25iplg0;
    }
}
```

Note the assignment is to some other value, not `foo`. How can I assign static a value to `foo` in bytecode using byte-buddy?

#### Other approaches I've tried that haven't worked:

##### Intercept method call

```
.intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Callable.class.getMethod("call")).on(() -> new Value("bar"), Callable.class)
    .setsField(ElementMatchers.named("foo"))
    .withAssigner(Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC));
```

This sets the value of `foo`, but the callable does not exist in the bytecode, so it gets an NPE when called:

```java
static {
        foo = (ExamplePlugin.Value)invocationTarget$j3n12b1.call();
    }
```

##### Use an initializer

```java
.initializer(new LoadedTypeInitializer.ForStaticField("foo", new Value("bar")))
```

This doesn't appear to be persisted in the bytecode at all.

Answer (score 1):

After `defineField`, you can set a `value`. This will be the constant pool value assigned to the field making it a compile time constant. For execution, you still need to assign the field as you already do.

Comment: That does indeed work! I accidentally oversimplified the problem when I wrote the question. This appears to work for primitives and for `String` types, but not for a custom class. I updated the question to better reflect the problem. How can I set a static field when the type is some arbitrary class? Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible as only primitives and strings can be so-called compile-time constants in the JVM.

Comment: That's a bummer :( thanks for the help